# Как реализовать определение доступных значений атрибутов сущностей в фильтре, в зависимости от уже выбранных значений?

Tags: алгоритм

Есть массив сущностей одного вида:

```
Entity
-attr1
-attr2
-...
-attrN
```

Каждый атрибут может иметь от 0 до n значений.

Пример:

```
Футболка 1:
- Цвет: синий
- Принт: null

Футболка 2:
- Цвет: синий, желтый
- Принт: на спине

Футболка 3:
- Цвет: красный
- Принт: на груди
```

Есть фильтр со всеми доступными значениями:

```
Цвет:
- синий
- желтый
- красный
Принт:
- на груди
- на спине
```

Требуется: при изменении одного из параметров фильтра убрать недостижимые варианты значений фильтра.
Пример:
Выбрали "Цвет: красный", фильтр должен изменить свои доступные значения на:

```
Цвет:
- синий    (выводится, так как при изменении цвета - вывод не будет нулевым) 
- желтый   (выводится, так как при изменении цвета - вывод не будет нулевым)
- красный  (выбран) 
Принт:
- на груди
- на спине (значение исчезло, так как таких свойств у оставшегося товара нет)
```

Буду благодарен за любые подсказки, направления.
Сам вижу 1 вариант: построить автомат, в который занести перестановки доступных атрибутов товаров.
(+) - слово входит в автомат.
Пример слов автомата для "футболка 2":

```
синий (+)
желтый (+)
на спине(+)
синий, на спине(+)
на спине, синий (+)
желтый, на спине(+)
на спине, желтый (+)
```

Тогда для проверки доступности атрибута - в автомат будет достаточно подать слово из выбранных значений фильтра, с заменой проверяемого значения атрибута в нем. В данном варианте - смущает сложность построения автомата, так как для получения всех перестановок атрибутов товара, понадобится до n! итераций, что показывает большую сложность алгоритма.

Answer (score 0):

А нельзя это сделать в лоб?

Проходим по всем атрибутам, для каждого:

1. отфильтровываем список сущностей по остальным атрибутам, указанным в фильтре;
2. собираем все возможные значения атрибута из отфильтрованного списка.

Например, для атрибута «принт»:

1. фильтруем по оставшимся атрибутам (цвет=красный) — остается одна сущность №3;
2. собираем у оставшихся сущностей значение «принт» — «на груди».

Если список хранится в памяти, то это все выполнится за *O(M*N)*, где *M* — количество атрибутов, а *N* — количество сущностей. Если в БД, то при желании можно все доступные значения собрать одним громоздким запросом. Возможно, это можно сделать эффективнее, но этот вариант первым пришел в голову.

Comment: Нет, данное решение не является масштабируемым, и будет плохо работать даже с "условно" большим количеством данных. В моем варианте получается зависимость только от количества значений атрибутов. Пример 10000 сущностей, 10 атрибутов на 200 значений (по 20 на атрибут). В вашем варианте получится О(100000), в моем, по готовому автомату O(200), но тут меня смущает сама сложность построения.

Comment: @testtestov Эта оценка не включает в себя время на построение автомата. Вообще, реалистичная оценка количества операций не может быть меньше чем количество сущностей.

Comment: Да, но автомат не нужно перестраивать перед каждым использованием фильтра, и не нужно хранить пол бд в памяти/кэше и.т.д. Про оценку - не понял. Сущности в оценке для автомата - не причем. Автомат содержит все доступные слова, которые составляются из возможных значений атрибутов, проверка же "слова" на валидность - не будет зависеть от количества сущностей, но будет от количества атрибутов, что не существенно при их количестве и малом времени проверки.

Comment: @testtestov Автомат нужно будет обновлять при каждом добавлении/удалении сущности. Мое решение не предполагает такого предрасчета. Возможно кто-нибудь предложит другое решение. Если хотите именно строить автомат, то рекомендую в вопросе уточнить ограничения на количество атрибутов и значений, ведь количество состояний в автомате в худшем случае растет пропорционально произведению количества значений для всех атрибутов.

Comment: Да, нужно, но в вашем - нужно работать со всеми данными, что дает похожую проблему - инвалидация данных в кэше/памяти. Количество состояний, еще одна часть, которая меня смущает, но ее можно уменьшить до вменяемого уровня - упорядочиванием данных + информацией о том, что будут похожие состояния и переходы - можно минимизировать автомат. Именно поэтому я и написал сюда, в надежде на то, что люди поделятся своим опытом в данной теме, возможно есть какие-то решения - не лежащие на поверхности. Благодарю за ваш ответ.

Comment: @testtestov Думаю, что СУБД должна справиться с кэшированием/индексированием данных на относительно небольших объемах (миллионы строк), но, да, здесь тоже есть над чем поработать. Надеюсь что кто-нибудь еще предложит варианты, которые подойдут Вам лучше..